# Why don't we count the omer with a bracha during the day?

Tags: blessing, sefirat-ha-omer

Seem that the commandment is to count, why do we make a distinction between counting during the day and at night?

Comment: http://imhm.blogspot.com/2017/01/blog-post_23.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Torah commands us to count the Omer "מהחל חרמש בקמה" ([Devarim 16:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.16.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), ("When the sickle 'begins' with the stalks"). Thus, it is assumed that the Omer should be counted when the stalks for the Korban Omer should be cropped.

The mitzva of קצירת העומר (cropping of the omer) applies at night ([Menachos 71a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.71a.4-5?lang=bi)), and it is disputed amongst the Rishonim whether it is acceptable if done by day.
Thus, the Shulchan Aruch ([OC 489:7-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.489.7-8?lang=bi)) rules (following the Rosh) that if one forgot at night, he should count by day, but without a b'racha (see [Tur  OC, 489](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.489.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: I ask you the same question i asked above. what does the first wheat cut have to do when we count each day?

Comment: @soandos, Read the first sentence of this post. The Torah commands us to count when we cut. According to those Rishonim who hold that it *must* be done at night, chazal learned from this verse that the time at which we must do both are correlated, even though a simple reading of the verse would not necessitate such a position. (Simply, it would mean that we *start* counting the omer once we begin to cut.) But from the fact that the Torah mentioned the קצירה when it clearly didn't have to, chazal's d'rasha is justified.

Comment: @jake: If in fact we should count at night, then why is counting during the day worth anything?

Comment: @soandos, Some rishonim hold that the cropping, if done by day, is perfectly acceptable. According to these rishonim, counting during the day with a b'racha is fine. However, since we don't know who is corrrect, the Rosh writes that one should count, but without a b'racha in case you are not really fulfilling the mitzva.

Comment: In other words there's a general concept by Omer, when we have a Safek: A safek works to be yotzei the Omer, but when there's a Safek you cannot make a Bracha. On the other hand, the next night you can make a Bracha, because then it becomes a sfeik sfeikah...

Comment: If there is an opinion that says it not good, then why would we continue counting with a bracha afterwards?

Comment: @yydl, Exactly. This concept is not specific to omer, but to making b'rachos in general. *Safek b'rachos l'hakel.* However, since there is a further safek if each night is its own mitzva or the whole 49 days are one big mitzva, the next night there is a "s'fek s'feika" in your favor. Thus you may make a b'racha.

Comment: @soandos, see my comment to @yydl. The next night, there is another dispute to consider. Some hold that that night is its own mitzva, while others hold that it's not. So you'll have "s'fek s'feika" as follows: Even if you did not fulfill the mitzva yesterday by counting by day, perhaps you may even still make a b'racha since this night is its own mitzva. This allows you to count with a b'racha.

Comment: @jake: Apologies, but if there is that original safek, why do we say a bracha on any but the first night?

Comment: @soandos, Good question. I think the answer is as follows: Generally, when we have a mitzva that encompasses many days, we say a b'racha each day anew. For example, we have the mitzva to learn Torah our whole lives, and yet we say the b'racha over again each day instead of just saying it once when we reach bar mitzva age. I think the same would apply to omer, and that we would make a b'racha each day even according to those who hold of the continuous 49-day mitzva.

Comment: "and it is disputed amongst the Rishonim whether it is acceptable if done by day." -- who are the Rishonim?

Comment: @Yehoshua, see B"Y and Bach [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2070). Essentially,  Tosafos and Behag on one side with Rosh, Ran, and Rabbeinu Tam on the other.

Answer (score 4):

The cutting of the Omer was done at night, and therefore the counting of the Omer is done with a Bracha only at night. (Tosafos HaRosh, Megilla 20b)

Comment: What does one have to do with the other?

Comment: Just like if the omer was not cut at night it is not valid, so too the blessing "counting" of the omer must be done at night.

Comment: the counting has nothing to do with the korban though...

Comment: I guess the Tosafos HaRosh disagrees with your contention.

Comment: So why do you think he thinks that they have something in common?

Comment: According to this why count during the day at all??

Answer (score 3):

I heard a *shiur* last week where it was related to the word תמימות/complete (in שבע שבתות *תמימות* תהיינה/they should be seven *complete* weeks).  A *halakhic* day begins at night, so in order for it to be counted "completely," the counting needs to be done at night.

According to [R' Soloveitchik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik), when you "make up" a missed night by counting during the day, you aren't actually fulfilling the *mitzva*; rather, you are just enabling yourself to count with a *bracha* on subsequent nights.  "Counting" can only be done if you count consecutively, so if you count 1 and skip 2, you can't then count 3.  By counting 2 during the day, you've maintained the continuity so that you can still count 3.

Answer (score -1):

While not a mainstream practice, there is a Tosfos on [Menachos 66a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.66a.16?lang=bi) that states that a person is allowed to make a bracha & count sefirah when there's still light outside (ie when it's doubtful whether it is nighttime yet).

Tosfos (ibid) *s.v.* "***[zecher l'mikdash hu](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.66a.16?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Menachot.66a.16.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)***" begins his commentary by stating:

> **נראה דבספק חשיכה יכול לברך** ואין צריך להמתין עד שיהא ודאי לילה כיון שהוא ספיקא דרבנן
>
> It seems that **when it is doubtful whether it's dark one can make a bracha** [for Sefiras Ha'omer], and a person does not need to wait until he's sure it is definitely night, since it is a safek mi'drabanan