# Why no bracha if you count the omer during the day?

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer

What is the logic behind not saying a bracha on counting the omer during the day?

The omer was not brought at night, presumably.

Comment: "The omer was not brought at night, presumably." Why do you presume that?

Comment: You should read https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71788/759

Comment: You probably want to reread Devarim 16:9 which says when to start counting

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think you should copy-paste that answer hither.

Comment: @DoubleAA  I presume that because the Temple was locked up for the night.  Only some housekeeping was done before closing for the night. Do you have reason to think the omer was brought at night?

Comment: @DoubleAA What about Devarim 16:9 speaks to time of day? Since it is difficult to harvest in the dark, that would argue for only saying the bracha in the daytime. But that was not the point of my question.

Comment: @YehudaW Devarim 16:9 shows that your thoughts about when you expect the Omer to have been offered are totally irrelevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Please explain the logic of your recent comment ("irrelevant"). I do not understand.

Comment: The relevant time is when the barley was cut, not when it was offered. It's an explicit Pasuk. I'm not sure what's confusing. "From when you start to cut you should start to count" couldn't be any clearer

Comment: @DoubleAA How do we know, from the pasuk, at what time of day the Omer was cut? Or are you saying something else and I am missing your point?

Comment: @YehudaW "How do we know, from the pasuk, at what time of day the Omer was cut?" You don't from that Pasuk. But Devarim 16:9 shows that your thoughts about when you expect the Omer to have been offered are totally irrelevant.

Comment: I was unable to find the (earlier) duplicate MY Q&A when I posted my question.  Will the person who found this Q&A please tell me how they found it: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7428/why-dont-we-count-the-omer-with-a-bracha-during-the-day

Answer (score 1):

The counting of the *Omer* is done at the time when the *Omer* was cut, which is done (ideally at least, see below) at night. It doesn't have to do with when the *Omer* was offered ([Shulchan Aruch Harav OC 489:3](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/489/3.htm))

As far as why we don't say a *berachah* when counting by day, he explains the reason is because there's a *machlokes* whether the *Omer* may be cut by day if it was not cut by night (which would reflect on us counting the *Omer* then), so because of the rule "*Safek berachos lehakel*" (if we're unsure whether to say a *berachah* or not, we rule to be lenient, and not say the *berachah*, in order to avoid saying Hashem's name in vain), we don't say a *berachah*.