# Repeating Sefiras Haomer the Next Day

Tags: synagogue, sefirat-ha-omer

I have noticed in some Shuls the Congregants repeat the counting of the Omer by day time (without a Brocha). What is the source to do this? Is this done as a precaution just in case one forgot to count the previous night, or is there a reason to recount by day?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Orthodox Congregation that I attended years ago in Boro Park that always said it in the morning prior to saying Baruch Sheamar. The reason was in case someone forgot the previous evening they would remember and thus be able to continue saying in the evening with a Bracha.

Comment: The people in Shul before Baruch Sheamar are probably not the people most likely to have forgotten to count the night before.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Perhaps, however those people are not there after Aleinu either.

Comment: So they should interrupt after kaddish titkabbel just like they do at maariv

Answer (score 0):

The mitzvah of counting Omer with a blessing is only at night, as explained [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7465/5275). If one forgets, he may count the next day without a blessing.

Thus, it is as you surmised. The congregation is doing it as a reminder. It would help, perhaps, if you stated what type of shul, congregation you attend. I'm guessing that it is not Orthodox. No Orthodox shul that I have attended does this congregationally, as many of their people have counted at night either by attending the minyan, or they assume that people have done it. Regardless, most shuls will have the Gabbai announce after davening, "Last night we counted xx", and that reminds someone who forgot to say it, himself. I.e., no Orthodox place I know of does a congregational counting during the day.

It's possible that your shul may have less or non-educated people or travelers / visitors attending Shacharit who don't know the bracha and the rules that well. You're rav may be trying to cater to their needs.

Comment: @danf the Shul in question is an Orthodox one. That was part of my query being that the Congregants have most probably all counted the previous night & like you say someone could just announce what the day's Omer is. That is why I asked my question. Perhaps I can ask the Rabbi before I accept.